# Should POSIX shell support SIGPOLL signal?

Tags: shell, signals, posix

I have never used POLL signal, but it is listed as some signal that has default action to do abnormal termination of the process:

https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/signal.h.html

It is marked with "Obsolescent" and as such Strictly Conforming POSIX Applications shall not use it.

I found that if I try to trap such a signal in bash (5.0.17) or dash (0.5.10) I get error:

> trap: POLL: bad trap

Does that make the shells not POSIX compliant?

P.S. tested by lksh (mksh package version 58-1 in Ubuntu Linux 20.04) in the same system:

```
#!/bin/lksh
sub() {
    trap 'echo sub SIGPOLL; trap - POLL; exit' POLL
    sleep 3 &
    wait $!
    return 0
}
sub &
pid=$!
sleep 1
kill -s POLL -- $pid
wait $pid
echo $?
trap 'echo SIGPOLL; trap - POLL; kill -s POLL -- $$' POLL
kill -s POLL -- $$
echo not here
```

outputs

```
sub SIGPOLL
157
SIGPOLL
I/O possible
```

Comment: Does `kill -l` list the `POLL` signal at all in your environment?

Comment: @Kusalananda it depends on the shell I run it in. For `dash` and `bash` it does not. For `lksh` it does.

Comment: Can you trap it in `lksh`?

Comment: @Kusalananda trap definition gives no error, but I am not able to catch the signal by it. At least with the default trap it will print "I/O possible" in stderr and exit with status 157. If I define `trap '' POLL` it will ignore the signal.

Comment: @Kusalananda  see the edited question

Answer (score 2):

No, both shells are conformant in this regard.

Bash [does support SIGPOLL](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/support/signames.c?h=bash-5.1&id=8868edaf2250e09c4e9a1c75ffe3274f28f38581#n282) *on systems that have it*, [as does dash](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/utils/dash/dash.git/tree/src/mksignames.c#n211):

> ```
> #if defined (SIGPOLL) /* Pollable event (for streams)  */
> signal_names[SIGPOLL] = "SIGPOLL";
> #endif
> ```

If your system doesn't have it, the system might itself be non-conformant, but there's nothing to trap.

There is an argument to make that `trap` [is required](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#trap) to support all of the signals named [in the table](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/signal.h.html), and that therefore attempting to trap SIGPOLL should be a noop instead of an error even on a system that was itself non-conformant (though conformance is defined at the system level).

However, SIGPOLL is *also* listed as part of the [XSI Streams feature](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_06) (XSR), which is optional, so a script that uses functionality from it could only be portable to another system that supported XSI Streams. Such a system would also include the POLL signal, and the shells would therefore pick that up as well.

This is conformant behaviour.

Comment: Please see my comment to the question.

Comment: That doesn't change anything here.

Comment: So my system has XSR and SIGPOLL when I use `lksh`, but not when I use `dash`?!

Comment: Well, I didn't comment on lksh. Generally on Linux the SIGPOLL constant is never more than an alias for SIGIO, not a distinct signal, but POSIX conformance is defined at the system level, not individual programs—if you got packages from your vendor and they have elected not to support XSI Streams, there's no issue with a program not supporting a gated feature. That is something to take up with Canonical in this instance, rather than the shells individually (it could be a choice, an oversight, a default, who knows). Both Bash and Dash are set up to be conformant in this respect, vendor willing.

Comment: Ubuntu doesn't strive for strict POSIX conformance, though, so they may just not care, which is fine too. I wouldn't be writing new scripts that used `trap POLL`, but I can definitely see the argument for treating it as a noop to ease migration from systems that do have it. It's just not a conformance requirement unless the system claims XSI streams.

Comment: So where would SIGPOLL be defined for e.g. dash, if XSI Streams were wanted to be supported?

Comment: I am interested in writing portable scripts that do e.g. some cleanup operation on termination (possibly caused by various signals) so it is a bit difficult, if I do not know which signals the script should be prepared for.

Comment: I suppose I can't even make traps for signals marked with XSI in the table if I just require POSIX conformance.

Comment: The answer links to the relevant source code for both. For the packages, ask the integrator. Note that systems may also have *more* signals than POSIX defines. Nothing is stopping you writing explicitly conditional code to set traps, though.